# Ubuntu slows down after a while

Tags: google-chrome

I don't know why. It's happening after I install Ubuntu. (1-2 days later)

I'm using Chrome (64-bit - last version) and Pidgin at the same time. It's just that. First opening is normal but when I use Chrome for a while, ubuntu is slowing down. (I have 1 active extension for Chrome, it's for new tab) But everything is okay when I use Chrome with Microsoft Windows.

Maybe my system isn't good. But my graphic card is really bad because I'm using onboard. (Foxconn g41mxe motherboard, Intel g41)

```
Ram: 2 GB
CPU: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5400 @ 2.70GHz × 2 
Graphic: Intel g41,
OS Type: 64-bit
Disk: 201 GB (for home directory, I'm using 50 GB for root directory)
Swap size: 4096 MB
HDD: 1 TB, new
*I've installed zram also*
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome really hogs up memory. This makes Linux to try to free up as much memory as possible for it, by swapping out essential parts of system, which makes it slow.
Try reducing `vm.swappiness` and maybe zram was not the best idea on 2GB either. This is too low for today programs, and you should take measures to make it work.
Maybe try some memory-efficient browsers like qupzilla?

Comment: Thank you :) I've changed the vm.swappiness to 10 already. But memory-efficient browsers aren't enough for me. Already tried.  I guess it's happening to Chrome after I watch some Youtube video.. Also, should I remove the zram?

Comment: Try running Chrome with option `--single-process`

Comment: Chrome is running on `--single-process` mode now.  What does this do?

Comment: Makes it use a bit less memory.